# Using linux not to crash but freeze as in windows

Tags: linux, windows, out-of-memory

i have an script that is taking a lot of memory to use and it is just "killed" or cannot be assigned more memory. When i run that same script on windows it consumes my whole memory and freezes my pc. I want the same to happen in my linux server instead of killing the process.

I have tried changinc vm.overcommit_memory to 0, 1 and 2 but none of them work, i tried some other things like disabling the oom killer in linux but cant find the value vm.oom-killer, please help

update:
Another solution would be to limit the memory it is using for example 10gb but if it exceedes dont consume more or kill the process, just let if finish.

Comment: So let me get this straight ...  You *want* to freeze the Linux server?  Why?

Comment: the process freezes windows for some time and i would like to have it running and finish like in windows instead of the process being killed, the results of the script is the important stuff.

Comment: How do you expect it to finish without being given more memory?  And how do you expect it to be given more memory if there isn't any more?  Do you want it to just wait and hope that more becomes available later?  Or, maybe you just want to add a bunch of swap, so that the process can successfully allocate memory and proceed, even though it makes the system very slow (but not literally "frozen").

Comment: i think what im trying to get to is what you mention at the end of your response. 
In windows i can still watch my screen at 2fps when running the script and i want my script to run in the same way but in linux. I am not sure about the swapping thing you mention can you refer me to a link for documentation about it? thanks